# JavaScript deletes JQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new with JavaScript and JQuery. I want to use the two and I have made a test example to learn. The script shows the width and height of the browser and the screen:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">   
        window.onload = function() {
            document.write( document.body.clientWidth + ' x ' + document.body.clientHeight);
        }   
</script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script>    
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( 'body' ).append( $( window ).width() + 'X' + $( document ).height() );
        });
</script>
```

When I run the file, there are only the javascript instructions, jquery instructions doesn`t appear. I checked when javascript code is between /**/, jquery instructions are OK.

How can I fix it?

Comment: That's what `document.write` does, it overwrites the document

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As `document.write` writes to the document stream, calling `document.write` on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls `document.open` **which will clear the document.**

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write)

In other words, using `document.write` in the `window.onload` handler replaces the entire document with what you're writing.

One of many ways to solve it is to use an element and set it's `innerHTML` instead

```
<div id="elem"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">   
        window.onload = function() {
            document.getElementById('elem').innerHTML = document.body.clientWidth + ' x ' + document.body.clientHeight;
        }   
</script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script>    
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( 'body' ).append( $( window ).width() + 'X' + $( document ).height() );
        });
</script>
```